# Is it possible to assign two structures of different type?

Tags: c++, structure

My need is to assign a structures to another similar structure. Just the names are different. If it were the same name we could use `=` (assignment) operator directly.

I don't want to use `memcpy()` as it will copy bits.

```
struct first {
  int i;
  char c;
};

struct second {
  int i;
  char c;

  //we can overload assignment operator to copy field.
  void operator = ( struct first& f) {
      i=f.i;
      c=f.c;
  }
};

int main()
{
  struct first f;
  f.i=100;
  f.c='a';
  struct second s=f; 
}
```

But I am getting compilation error.

> error: conversion from "first" to non-scalar type "second" requested.

Not sure if it is possible?

Comment: Here you are not assigning. You are copying objects. So copy constructor required

Comment: Initialization != assignment. Either write a constructor for `second` that takes `first` as a argument, or write a conversion operator, to `second`, in `first`.

Comment: You could use the cast-through-a-union idiom, will also make sure compiler does not do any aliasing optimizations that may break your code. Or just memcpy, very brute force.

Answer (score 6):

You need a constructor to use

```
struct second s=f;
```

such as:

```
struct second{
  int i;
  char c;
  second(first const& f) : i(f.i), c(f.c) {}

  ...

};
```

To use the assignment operator, use:

```
second s;  // No need to use struct in C++
s = f;
```

BTW, a proper interface and implementation for the `operator=` function should be:

```
second& operator=(first const& f)
{
   i=f.i;
   c=f.c;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and helpful reply.
My bad, Had got in mind that it is assignment, but its copy :).

Answer (score 1):

use as follows. Then it will work. Or create copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct first{
int i;
char c;
};
struct second{
int i;
char c;
//we can overload assignment operator to copy field.
void operator = ( struct first& f)
{
    i=f.i;
    c=f.c;
}
};

int main()
{
  struct first f;
  f.i=100;
  f.c='a';
  struct second s;
  s=f; 
}
```